# Function template specialization with overloads with different number of parameters

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-specialization

Consider the following (invalid) code sample:

```
// a: base template for function with only one parameter
template<typename T>
void f(T t) { }

// b: base tempalte for function with two parameters
template<typename T1, typename T2>
void f(T1 t1, T2 t2) { }

// c: specialization of a for T = int
template<>
void f<int>(int i) { }

// d: specialization for b with T1 = int - INVALID
template<typename T2>
void f<int, T2>(int i, T2 t2) { }

int main() {
    f(true);        // should call a
    f(true, false); // should call b

    f(1);           // should call c
    f(1, false);    // should call d
}
```

I've read [this walk-through](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm) on why, in general, partial function template specializations won't work, and I think I understand the basic reasoning: there are cases where function template specializations and overloading would make certain calls ambiguous (there are good examples in the article).

However, is there a reason why *this specific example* wouldn't work, other than "the standard says it shouldn't"? Does anything change if I can guarantee (e.g. with a `static_assert`) that the base template is never instantiated? Is there any other way to achieve the same effect?

---

What I actually want to achieve is to create an extendable factory method

```
template<typename T>
T create();
```

which also has a few overloads taking input parameters, e.g.

```
template<typename T, typename TIn>
T create(TIn in);
template<typename T, typename TIn1, typename TIn2>
T create(TIn1 in1, TIn2 in2);
```

In order to ensure that all necessary factory methods are present, I use `static_assert` in the function base templates, so that a compiler error is generated if the create method is called with template arguments for which no specialization has been provided.

I want these to be function templates rather than class templates because there will be quite a lot of them, and they will all use input from the same struct hierarchy, so instantiating 10 factories instead of one comes with some overhead that I'd like to avoid (not considering the fact that the code gets much easier to understand this way, if I can just get it to work...).

Is there a way to get around the problem outlined in the first half of this post, in order to achieve what I've tried to get at with the second half?

---

In response to [iavr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22966556/38055):

I could do this with plain overloading, which would (given the templates above) give something like

```
template<typename TIn2>
A create(bool, TIn2);
template<typename TIn2>
A create(int, TIn2);
```

if I need two different partial specializations with `T = A`, `TIn1` specified and `TIn2` still unspecified. This is a problem, since I have some cases (which are really text-book cases for meta-programming and templates) where I know that, for example, one of the arguments will be a `std::string`, and the other will be of some type that has a property `fields` and a property `grids`, which are of types `std::vector<field>` and `std::vector<grid>` respectively. I don't know all the types that will ever be supplied as the second argument - I know for sure that there will be more of them than the ones I currently have implemented - but the implementation of the method will be exactly the same.

While writing up this update, I think I've figured out a way to redesign the implementations so that there is no need for the partial specialization - basically, I do the following to cover the case outlined above:

```
template<>
A create<A, std::vector<field>, std::vector<grid>>(std::vector<field> fs, std::vector<grid> gs);
```

and then I have to change the calling signature slightly, but that's OK.

Comment: I believe you can work-around the lack of partial function specialization by using a function-object as classes can be partially specialized (e.g. see second alternative in http://accu.org/index.php/journals/385)

Comment: Is your goal to make `create` method where you specify the `T`, and based on that, it uses the arguments passed in (0 or more) to perform the creation?  And are you using C++11?

Comment: @DaveS: Spot on, for both questions.

Comment: @TomasLycken If the problem is to specialize for 2nd arguments having members like `fields`, `grids`, you can do that with `std::enable_if`. But maybe I'm just guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want overloading, and want to be able to specialize from a separate file, then I think you should base it on the solution on the link from your question.  It involves making a static method on a class that you specialize.  From my reading of the question, you're only interested in specializing on the `T`, not on the number of arguments, which you intend to forward.  In C++11, you can do the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
using namespace std;


template<typename T>
struct factory_impl;
// Left unspecified for now (which causes compliation failure if
// not later specialized

template<typename T, typename... Args>
T create(Args&&... args)
{
   return factory_impl<T>::create(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}


// Note, this can be specified in a header in another translation
// unit. The only requirement is that the specialization
// be defined prior to calling create with the correct value
// of T
template<>
struct factory_impl<int>
{
   // int can be constructed with 0 arguments or 1 argument
   static int create(int src = 0)
   {
     return src;
   }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   int i = create<int>();
   int j = create<int>(5);
   // double d = create<double>(); // Fails to compile

   std::cout << i << " " << j << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Live example http://ideone.com/7a3uRZ

Edit: In response to your question, you could also make `create` a member function of a class, and pass along some of that data with the call or take action before or after

```
struct MyFactory
{

   template<typename T, typename... Args>
   T create(Args&&... args)
   {
      T ret = factory_impl<T>::create(data, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
      // do something with ret
      return ret;
   }

   Foo data; // Example
};
```

Comment: This implementation looks good in most aspects. Are the specialized `create` methods scoped somehow? Would it be possible to encapsulate them in a (non-templated) factory class that can hold some data for them to use, and then forward calls to `factory_impl` anyway?

Comment: @TomasLycken:  See update.   You can also insert code prior to calling the `factory_impl`

Answer (score 2):

I share your concerns that maybe in this particular case there would be no problem having function template partial specializations, but then again, that's the way it is, so what would be your problem using plain overloading?

```
// a: base template for function with only one parameter
template<typename T>
void f(T t) { }

// b: base template for function with two parameters
template<typename T1, typename T2>
void f(T1 t1, T2 t2) { }

// c: specialization of a for T = int
void f(int i) { }

// d: specialization for b with T1 = int
template<typename T2>
void f(int i, T2 t2) { }
```

This also takes less typing and I get this is why you don't want to use function objects (which would have partial specialization).

Comment: This is probably a decent work-around (and feels a lot less clumsy than several of the approaches suggested [here](http://accu.org/index.php/journals/385)), but there is one major drawback: it requires me to declare all the different overloads inside the class definition. Ideally, I'd like to be able to "tuck on" factory methods from other headers and compilation units, which would be possible using template specialization only.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the problem. If you could give more details (e.g. by editing the question), I might help. But from what you say, I feel there are ways to make everything work.

Comment: Hm. I wrote an update, but while doing that I found a way to refactor out the need for partial function template specialization (for now). Take a look and see what you think.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple workaround using a class template specialization:

```
template <typename, typename...>
struct Creator;

template <typename T, typename TIn>
struct Creator<T, TIn>
{
    T call(TIn in)
    {
        // ...
    }
};

template<typename T, typename TIn1, typename TIn2>
struct Creator<T, TIn1, TIn2>
{
    T call(TIn1 in1, TIn2 in2)
    {
        // ...
    }
};

template <typename R, typename... Arguments>
R Create(Arguments&&... arguments)
{
    return Creator<R, Arguments...>::call(std::forward<Arguments>(arguments)...);
}
```